# Hiding Apache entry in HTTP header

Tags: apache-2.2, web

We are using Springsource ERS Apache in our environment, regarding to hardening part Even after using ServerSignature Off, still we are receiving the

Server:Apache in the header information.

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

You could install [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/), a free add-on that will allow you to change the Server: header to what ever you wish, for example you could make it say "IIS" or just make it say "None of your business!" :)

Comment: Could you ever tried mod_security installation with Springsource ERS Apache , becoz we are facing lot  errors while doing "make" ]

Comment: No, I haven't. Instead of trying to compile it from source, why not see if there is a package available for your OS?

Comment: I think for Solaris , there wont be any package for solaris .. if its available means pls share ... the link where to download

Answer (score 0):

The details as in the signature or headers are controlled by the [`ServerTokens`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive. You cannot show less than "Apache" without modifying the source code and re-compiling Apache.

You shouldn't worry too much about this, there are other ways to get to know that you're using Apache: error pages (not just 404, but bad headers for example) or requesting `.ht` files (denied by default in Apache).

Comment: Hi Lekensteyn, we are using customized  error pages to avoid such vulnerability and  disabled .ht  access in our environment, came to know using mod_security we can completely disable this info , but the compilation of mod_security with Springsource has not been succeufully completed..